# Intel XDK and remote images

Tags: javascript, image

Let's say I want to load some json data to my app and then display a products information based on that returned data in an app built with intel xdk.

eg.

```
{"Title":"Product 1","ImageURL":"http://images.com/images/product/1/image.jpg"}
```

I can write the javascript to populate an `<img>` tag with the returned URL, but how do I then get this to display this in my app ?, as `<img src="http://images.com/images/product/1/image.jpg" />`, does not display the requested image. It seems to only work for a locally hosted images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in this [W3School article](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp) loading the image using the tag & src the way you specified should work. If it's not working, then it's either because your HTML isn't valid or the image isn't at the specified source. I would recommend using an [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to verify your HTML is correct, and making a browser request to the url to ensure the image is at that location.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Yep...you're right...The actual URL I was using was in fact valid, but I had forgotten I had password protected the root directory on the domain while I was deploying the website for demoing!